# Segmented regression in R: interpreting the other coefficients

Tags: generalized-linear-model, interpretation, segmented-regression

I am running segmented regression using the R package 'segmented'. The original binomial logistic regression has two coefficients, approach_km (continuous), and sea (dichotomous) that explain the probability of the dependent variable occurring. I am interested in investigating if there is a break-point in the regression slope for approach_km.

Here are the coefficient estimates from the original non-segmented glm

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -1.15563    0.17352  -6.660 2.74e-11 ***
approach_km -0.03915    0.01140  -3.432 0.000598 ***
sea2         0.34501    0.20515   1.682 0.092615 .
```

Here are the estimates after running the model through the segmented function

```
Estimated Break-Point(s):
   Est. St.Err 
 3.794  1.134 

t value for the gap-variable(s) V:  0 

Meaningful coefficients of the linear terms:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)    -0.08233    0.32692  -0.252    0.801  
approach_km    -0.49096    0.19776  -2.483    0.013 *
sea2            0.27182    0.21141   1.286    0.199  
U1.approach_km  0.49085    0.19817   2.477       NA
```

A Davies' test indicates that the differences in the two slope estimates is significant.

The question I have is how do I interpret the coefficient sea? I see that the estimate (and the p value) changes in the segmented output. Does this mean that this is the best estimate for the value of the coefficient for both of the estimated slopes? Since the sea coefficient is not significant we can assume that this variable will not statistically alter the overall effect or interpretation of the model but I am interested in how I would interpret this result if it was in fact significant.